# Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence during document parsing

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse a document from bytes as follows

```
String result = /* some valid xml document */
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
try {
    Document document = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes()));
} catch (MalformedByteSequenceException e) {
    System.out.println("(MalformedByteSequenceException ) " + e.getMessage());
}
```

A MalformedByteSequenceException is thrown and the next is printed in the console

```
"(MalformedByteSequenceException ) Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence."
```

The weird thing is that the same code works in my local environment (Windows 10) but not in the remote environment (Windows Server 2012)

I tried to replicate the error in my local environment changing TomEE version, from 1.7.4 to 1.7.1, I tried changing the JRE from 1.7.0_80 to 1.7.0, I tried copying the full Tomee folder from the remote system to my local machine, still the error only happens in the remote environment

Using `result.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` instead of `result.getBytes()` didn't work either.

Comment: Does your Unicode file have an encoding in the prolog?

Comment: the xml document comes from a webservice response, not from a file

Comment: Same question. Is there an encoding=?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Set this at the start of **setenv.bat**,

```
rem Set encoding
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I am not sure about the rationale behind this, but appear that the JVM is using some weird Windows encoding instead of the UTF-8 that you need

Answer (score 0):

Calling `String.getBytes()` is precisely the same as calling `String.getBytes("<value of file.encoding>")`.

However, there's no need to call that at all. Call `parse` with an `InputSource` set up over a `StringReader`.